# How to encode series of images into VP8 using WebM VP8 Encoder API? (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, encode, onvp8, vp8

How to transcode RGB images into VP8 frames (Keyframe + some dependent frames)?

So I created some images how to turn tham into VP8 now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need a codec library for VP8:

http://www.webmproject.org/code/build-prerequisites/

Using **libvpx** API you can then encode your RGB frames into VP8 frames.

Comment: ya but how exactly, where is the simplest possible example, found in examples/simple_encoder.c but its too complicated, how do I encode say 3 frames

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to go is to use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).

The latest release of ffmpeg (0.6) now supports the VP8 codec, and [building it is now easy](http://multimedia.cx/eggs/libvpx-0-9-1-and-ffmpeg-0-6/).

Then, [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) makes it simple to gather individual frames into a movive. [Here is a tutorial](http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/), but you can google for more results.

Comment: but how do u do it from C++

Comment: links are stale