# WebM encoder samples - How to encode a series of images into a WebM video

Tags: c++, video, webm

Are there any good examples on how to create a WebM video file suitable for streaming to a web browser using the open-source WebM encoding library? Where should I begin? I am the owner of a small business, so I don't want to get into legal issues with FFMpeg, and I can't seem to figure out how the vpx_encoder.h is supposed to work. I am also interested in performing the reverse to create a video player in my application.  I realize my question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029164/how-to-encode-series-of-images-into-vp8-using-webm-vp8-encoder-api-c-c), however, I found neither of the two answers satisfactory.

To be more specific; the images are coming from a GDI+ bitmap object.

Comment: To be more specific; the images are coming from a GDI+ bitmap object

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my code, I used DEVIL to handle image file and manually convert pixels from RGB to YV12.

http://code.google.com/p/ortholab/source/browse/WebMEnc/WebMEnc.cpp

Comment: link seems to be dead

Comment: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=ortholab is what it redirects to but it doesnt work