# How to encode RGB images (bitmaps) into VP8 format?

Tags: c#, encoding, webm, vp8

Anyone know how I could encode RGB images (24bppRgb) into VP8 format using C#? Basically I'm capturing the screen as bitmap frames and I want to encode them to reduce the size before sending.

From what I've seen there are only code examples for C++ not C#.
Suppose I'm asking for a C# [alternative to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029164/how-to-encode-series-of-images-into-vp8-using-webm-vp8-encoder-api-c-c).

Answer (score 0):

You could either port the code (a bit job I'm sure) or build an application in C++ which does the actual conversion, and then call that application via command line in C#, storing the result in a txt or a log file of some sort.

Comment: It is also possible to call c++ code from c#, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935664/possible-to-call-c-code-from-c, so you can keep the c++ version intact and just invoke it from c# for your encoding needs

Comment: also it seems the 2 answers aren't satisfactory there do you know how I can encode say 3 frames of ARGB data into a very short vp8 video just to get started from scratch?