# VP8 C/C++ source, how to encode frames in ARGB format to frame instead of from file

Tags: c++, c, uint8t, vp8

I'm trying to get started with the [VP8 library](https://github.com/webmproject/libvpx), I'm not building it [in the standard way they tell you to](https://www.webmproject.org/code/), I just loaded all of the main files and the "encoder" folder into a new Visual Studio C++ DLL project, and just included the C files in an extern "C" dll export function, which so far builds fine etc., I just have no idea where to start with the C++ API to encode, say, 3 frames of ARGB data into a very basic video, just to get started

The only example I could find is in the examples folder called `simple_encoder.c`, although their premise is that they are loading in another file already and parsing its frames then converting it, so it seems a bit complicated, I just want to be able to pass in a byte array of a few ARGB frames and have it output a very simple VP8 video

I've seen [How to encode series of images into VP8 using WebM VP8 Encoder API? (C/C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029164/how-to-encode-series-of-images-into-vp8-using-webm-vp8-encoder-api-c-c) but the accepted answer just links to [the build instructions](https://chromium.googlesource.com/webm/libvpx/+/master/README) and references [the general specification of the vp8 format](https://www.webmproject.org/docs/), the closest I could find there is [the example encoding parameters](https://www.webmproject.org/docs/encoder-parameters/) but I just want to do everything from C++ and I can't seem to find any other examples, besides for the default one `simple_encoder.c`?

Just to cite some of the relevant parts I think I understand, but still need more help on

```
//in int main...
...
vpx_image_t raw;
if (!vpx_img_alloc(&raw, VPX_IMG_FMT_I420, info.frame_width,
                     info.frame_height, 1)) {
    //"Failed to allocate image." error
}
```

So that part I think I understand for the most part, VPX_IMG_FMT_I420 is the only part that's not made in this file itself, but its in vpx_image.h, first as

```
#define VPX_IMG_FMT_PLANAR 
//then after...
typedef enum vpx_img_fmt {
    VPX_IMG_FMT_NONE,
    VPX_IMG_FMT_RGB24,   /**< 24 bit per pixel packed RGB */
    ///some other formats....
    VPX_IMG_FMT_ARGB,     /**< 32 bit packed ARGB, alpha=255 */

    VPX_IMG_FMT_YV12    = VPX_IMG_FMT_PLANAR | VPX_IMG_FMT_UV_FLIP | 1, /**< planar YVU */
    VPX_IMG_FMT_I420    = VPX_IMG_FMT_PLANAR | 2,
   
  } vpx_img_fmt_t; /**< alias for enum vpx_img_fmt */
```

So I guess part of my question is answered already just from writing this, that one of the formats is VPX_IMG_FMT_ARGB, although I don't where where it's defined, but I'm guessing in the above code I would replace it with

```
const VpxInterface *encoder = get_vpx_encoder_by_name("v8");

vpx_image_t raw;
VpxVideoInfo info = { 0, 0, 0, { 0, 0 } };

info.frame_width = 1920;
info.frame_height = 1080;
info.codec_fourcc = encoder->fourcc;
info.time_base.numerator = 1;
info.time_base.denominator = 24;

bool didIt = vpx_img_alloc(&raw, VPX_IMG_FMT_ARGB, 
          info.frame_width, info.frame_height/*example width and height*/, 1)
//check didIt..

vpx_codec_enc_cfg_t cfg;
vpx_codec_ctx_t codec;
vpx_codec_err_t res;

res = vpx_codec_enc_config_default(encoder->codec_interface(), &cfg, 0);
//check if !res for error

cfg.g_w = info.frame_width;
cfg.g_h = info.frame_height;
cfg.g_timebase.num = info.time_base.numerator;
cfg.g_timebase.den = info.time_base.denominator;
cfg.rc_target_bitrate = 200;

VpxVideoWriter *writer = NULL;

writer = vpx_video_writer_open(outfile_arg, kContainerIVF, &info);
//check if !writer for error

bool startIt = vpx_codec_enc_init(&codec, encoder->codec_interface(), &cfg, 0);
//not even sure where codec was set actually..


//check !startIt for error starting

//now the next part in the original is where it reads from the input file, but instead
//I need to pass in an array of some ARGB byte arrays..
//thing is, in the next step they use a while loop for 
//vpx_img_read(&raw, fopen("path/to/YV12formatVideo", "rb"))
//to set the contents of the raw vpx image allocated earlier, then
//they call another program that writes it to the writer object,
//but I don't know how to read the actual ARGB data directly into the raw image
//without using fopen, so that's one question (review at end)

//so I'll just put a placeholder here for the **question**

//assuming I have an array of byte arrays stored individually
//for simplicity sake
int size = 1920 * 1080 * 4;

uint8_t imgOne[size] = {/*some big byte array*/};
uint8_t imgTwo[size] = {/*some big byte array*/};
uint8_t imgThree[size] = {/*some big byte array*/};

uint8_t *images[] = {imgOne, imgTwo, imgThree};

int framesDone = 0;
int maxFrames = 3;

//so now I can replace the while loop with a filler function 
//until I find out how to set the raw image with ARGB data
while(framesDone < maxFrames) {
    magicalFunctionToSetARGBOfRawImage(&raw, images[framesDone]);
    
    encode_frame(&codec, &raw, framesDone, 0, writer);
    
    framesDone++;
}

//now apparently it needs to be flushed after

while(encode_frame(&codec, 0, -1, 0, writer)){}
vpx_img_free(&raw);
bool isDestroyed = vpx_codec_destroy(&codec);
//check if !isDestroyed for error

//now we gotta define the encode_Frames function, but simpler 
//(and make it above other function for reference purposes 
//or in header

static int encode_frame(
     vpx_codex_ctx_t *coydek, 
     vpx_image_t pic,
     int currentFrame, 
     int flags,
     VpxVideoWriter *koysayv/*writer*/
) {
    //now to substitute their encodeFrame function for
    //the actual raw calls to simplify things
    const DidIt = vpx_codec_encode(
        coydek,
        pic,
        currentFrame,
        1,//duration I think
        flags,//whatever that is
        VPX_DL_REALTIME//different than simlpe_encoder
    );
    
    if(!DidIt) return;//error here
    
    vpx_codec_iter_t iter = 0;
    const vpx_codec_cx_pkt_t *pkt = 0;
    int gotThings = 0;
    
    while(
        (pkt = vpx_codec_get_cx_data(
            coydek,
            &iter
        )) != 0
    ) {
        gotThings = 1;
        
        if(
            pkt->kind 
            == VPX_CODEC_CX_FRAME_PKT //don't exactly
            //understand this part
        ) {
            const 
            int 
            keyframe = (
                pkt
                    ->
                    data
                    .frame
                    .flags 
                    & 
                    VPX_FRAME_IS_KEY
            ) != 0; //don'texactly understand the
            //& operator here or how it gets the keyframe
            
            bool wroteFrame = vpx_video_writer_write_frame(
                koysayv,
                pkt->data.frame.buf
                //I'm guessing this is the encoded 
                //frame data
                ,
                pkt->data.frame.sz,
                pkt->data.frame.pts
            );
            
            if(!wroteFrame) return; //error
        }
    }
    
    return gotThings;
}
```

Thing is though, I don't know how to actually read the
ARGB data into the RAW image buffer itself, as mentioned
above, in the original example, they use
`vpx_img_read(&raw, fopen("path/to/file", "rb"))`
but if I'm starting off with the byte arrays themselves
then what function do I use for that instead of the file?

I have a feeling it can be solved by the source code for the [vpx_img_read found in tools_common.c](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/media/libvpx/libvpx/tools_common.c) function:

```
int vpx_img_read(vpx_image_t *img, FILE *file) {
  int plane;

  for (plane = 0; plane < 3; ++plane) {
    unsigned char *buf = img->planes[plane];
    const int stride = img->stride[plane];
    const int w = vpx_img_plane_width(img, plane) *
                  ((img->fmt & VPX_IMG_FMT_HIGHBITDEPTH) ? 2 : 1);
    const int h = vpx_img_plane_height(img, plane);
    int y;

    for (y = 0; y < h; ++y) {
      if (fread(buf, 1, w, file) != (size_t)w) return 0;
      buf += stride;
    }
  }

  return 1;
}
```

although I personally am not experienced enough to necessarily know how to get a single frames ARGB data in, I think the key part is `fread(buf, 1, w, file)` which seems to read parts of `file` into `buf` which represents `img->planes[plane];`, which I think then by reading into buf that automatically reads into `img->planes[plane];`, but I'm not sure if that is the case, and also not sure how to replace the fread from file to just take in a bye array that is alreasy loaded into memory...

Comment: Please read the description of the tags that you appliede to your question. Further, there is no such language as C/C++.

Comment: @ulrich tell the to the author of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029164/how-to-encode-series-of-images-into-vp8-using-webm-vp8-encoder-api-c-c obviously c/c++ is not a single language but c can be used within c++ which is what I want to do so they go together

Comment: bluejayke: @UlrichEckhardt won't see the comment unless you tag him properly I think. Regarding the language tags: All valid C code is not valid C++ code and vice versa. This looks like plain C.

Comment: @ted ok but the main point is that I would also accept solutions that call c functions from c++ of that's necessary, c++ code is able to include c functions, correct?

Comment: As long as the included code happens to follow C++ rules it should be ok. I'd compile the C code with a C compiler to minimize surprises since a C++ compiler may make assumptions (like, "since there will be no type-punning I can optimize with that in mind") that a C compiler won't make.

Comment: @ted exactly, so since it's possible to mix c and c++ code, then how is this tag invalid

Comment: I didn't say the tag is invalid. I just made a note about C not being a subset of C++. C has some rules that don't play nice with C++, but I think you should remove the C++ tag since there is only C code in the question (perhaps valid as C++). Another thing: You say "_I just want to do everything from C++_" but you haven't shown what you mean by that. You could just call the C functions, right?  Overall, this question needs focus i.m.o. Pick one of the problems you've encountered and ask a question about that specific problem and it'll be easier to find someone who can answer.

Comment: @ted what's not understood. The question is how to read the argb data into the image object, as stated at the end

Comment: If that's all you wonder about in this question the C++ tag makes even less sense. "_I just have no idea where to start with the C++ API to encode_" - Since there is no C++ API this makes it sound like you are about to write one and have questions about that. If you remove everything not necessary to perform the reading of argb data into the image object, it'll be much easier to digest.

Answer (score 1):

VPX_IMG_FMT_ARGB is not defined because not supported by libvpx (as far as I have seen). To compress an image using this library, you must first convert it to one of the supported format, like I420 (VPX_IMG_FMT_I420). The code here (not mine) : https://gist.github.com/racerxdl/8164330 do it well for the RGB format. If you don't want to use libswscale to make the conversion from RGB to I420, you can do things like this (this code convert a RGBA array of bytes to a I420 vpx_image that can be use by libvpx):

```
    unsigned int   tx       = <width of your image>
    unsigned int   ty       = <height of your image>
    unsigned char *image    = <array of bytes : RGBARGBA... of size ty*tx*4>
    vpx_image_t   *imageVpx = <result that must have been properly initialized by libvpx>

    imageVpx->stride[VPX_PLANE_U    ] = tx/2;
    imageVpx->stride[VPX_PLANE_V    ] = tx/2;
    imageVpx->stride[VPX_PLANE_Y    ] = tx;
    imageVpx->stride[VPX_PLANE_ALPHA] = tx;
    imageVpx->planes[VPX_PLANE_U    ] = new unsigned char[ty*tx/4];
    imageVpx->planes[VPX_PLANE_V    ] = new unsigned char[ty*tx/4];
    imageVpx->planes[VPX_PLANE_Y    ] = new unsigned char[ty*tx  ];
    imageVpx->planes[VPX_PLANE_ALPHA] = new unsigned char[ty*tx  ];

    unsigned char *planeY  = imageVpx->planes[VPX_PLANE_Y    ];
    unsigned char *planeU  = imageVpx->planes[VPX_PLANE_U    ];
    unsigned char *planeV  = imageVpx->planes[VPX_PLANE_V    ];
    unsigned char *planeA  = imageVpx->planes[VPX_PLANE_ALPHA];

    for (unsigned int y=0; y<ty; y++)
    {
        if (!(y % 2))
        {
            for (unsigned int x=0; x<tx; x+=2)
            {
                int r = *image++;
                int g = *image++;
                int b = *image++;
                int a = *image++;

                *planeY++ = max(0, min(255, (( 66*r + 129*g +  25*b) >> 8) + 16));
                *planeU++ = max(0, min(255, ((-38*r + -74*g + 112*b) >> 8) + 128));
                *planeV++ = max(0, min(255, ((112*r + -94*g + -18*b) >> 8) + 128));
                *planeA++ = a;

                r = *image++;
                g = *image++;
                b = *image++;
                a = *image++;

                *planeA++ = a;
                *planeY++ = max(0, min(255, ((66*r + 129*g + 25*b) >> 8) + 16));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (unsigned int x=0; x<tx; x++)
            {
                int const r = *image++;
                int const g = *image++;
                int const b = *image++;
                int const a = *image++;

                *planeA++ = a;
                *planeY++ = max(0, min(255, ((66*r + 129*g + 25*b) >> 8) + 16));
            }
        }
    }
```